# Replace a word between commas, at beginning of a sentence, its middle, or its end

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with some words separated by commas. I want to remove one of the words while maintaining the correct comma structure.

Example:

```
dan,brian,max
brian,dan,max
brian,max,dan
```

If "dan" is in the beginning of the line, the succeeding comma should be taken out.
If he's in the middle of the line one of the commas should be taken out.
if he's in the end of the line, the preceding comma should be taken out.

So the final output is:

```
brian,max
brian,max
brian,max
```

So far I've done it with two regex's, but i'm sure there's a way to do it in one line.

```
%s/^\@!\(,\)\?dan\(,\)\?/\2/ | %s/^dan,//
```

#### Edit:

It could be done like this, but it seems to me like a roundabout way.

```
%s/^\@!\(,\)\?dan\(,\)\?\|^\(dan,\)/\2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you need is just:

```
^dan,|,dan\b
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/btnIlf0oO4)

The trick is to capture the *leading* comma for the middle case, making it the same match for both middle and end cases.

As a replacement command:

```
%s/^dan,\|,dan\>//g
```

Note: If vim doesn't support word boundary `\b`, remove it

Comment: also better with word boundary, e.g. in case `foo,dangerous,bar,dan`

Comment: @kent thx, I don't have a terminal handy - does the word boundary need double escape in the command?

Comment: @Bohemian in vim, `\>` matches the end of a word. works like `\b`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this also,

```
%s/\<dan,\|,dan$//g
```

Comment: What if the file contained the name "jordan"?

Comment: replace dan with jordan ie, `%s/\bjordan,\|,jordan$//g`

Comment: No, I meant you still want to replace "dan", but the file now also contains "jordan". Your example will break, it should be something like `%s/\<dan,\|,dan$//g`.

Comment: Your update contains `\b` which matches a backspace, I think you meant `\<`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      re.sub(r"[,]+dan|dan[,]+","",x)
```

Substituting dan with blank.